# access event handlers for FMX styled objects

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

How can I access the event handler of a styled button. For example, this works:

```
ListBoxItem.StylesData['detail2.text'] := date;
```

but not this:

```
ListBoxItem.StylesData['downloadbutton.OnClick'] := LoadFileContent; //says not enough parameters. So when I put in 'LoadFileContent(nil) then I get an imcompatible types error message
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
uses
  //....
  System.Rtti;
  //....
  ListBoxItem.StylesData['downloadbutton.OnClick'] := TValue.From<TNotifyEvent>(LoadFileContent);
```